A movie about a superhero with a flying car
It's a recent (from no longer than 10 years), European (probably) movie, 
about a superhero and his flying car. The lead is a young (poor) guy goes to college and he loves a girl but she's with his rich friend who who drives a sport car.
In one scene in the beginning, there was a successful man given a lecture in their class and he asked something like "who wants and have the courage to ask for ## of money" and the lead did so he took ## out of his pocket and left them on the desk for him and walked out. 
The lead followed him and gave him the money back and asked him for advice about how to be successful and followed his advice by starting working in a delivering job with his car (legal job).
The other scene that I watched was by the end when he met the girl he loves at a restaurant and asked her why she's still  with their friend, despite of all his flaws, so she tells him that he don't really know him and he (the friend) is the hero with the flying car (His friend lied to her).
The lead didn't tell her the truth (that he is the superhero) but she found out in the end when he save her from the villain in a flying cars fight!

I found it. It's a Russian movie called Chernaya Molniya or "Black Lightning"

A Moscow college student's gift car from his parents turns out to be more than anyone expects when it flies, which he uses to become both a city guardian and a speedy floral delivery boy. 




